# Why do we use radians for polar coordinates rather than degrees?

Tags: polar-coordinates

Is there a specific reason why radians must be used when converting from Cartesian to Polar coordinates, is it just a convention or does it not matter at all?

Comment: https://qedinsight.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/why-radian-measure-makes-life-easier-in-mathematics-and-physics/

Comment: It's just a convention, but there aren't many reasons to use degrees and many to use radians.

Comment: Are you familiar with Euler's Formula, and its relationship to polar coordinates on the complex plane? That makes it very clear why radians are a natural measure of an angle for a complex number.

Comment: None of the answers use a nice unit circle and pi to show how useful and "natural" radians truly are, sadly. When you look at a unit circle and the angles involved, you look at it in radans. Converting to degrees is just an unnecessary step.

Comment: @Polygnome - to be honest that makes no sense. You look at it "in radians" if you are used to radians. There is nothing intrinsic about it.

Comment: You do know that degrees are just a convention as well, right? There is no reason why the natural order of the universe, space, and our reality would mandate 360 divisions of a circle over some other number...(tongue-in-cheek). But seriously, this convention probably goes all the way back to the Babylonians, who loved using base 60. We probably inherited the weird time conventions (24 hours, 60 mins, 60 secs) from them too. The reason base 60 has been in continuous used is because it makes division into smaller pieces easier; if you need a half, a third, or a quarter of a quantity.

Comment: @Davor: No, radians are the *intrinsic* way to measure angles. Imagine a slice of pie. How many radians is the angle it makes?  The ratio of the length of the crust to the length of the radius. It's not a question of convention; it is the most concise definition possible. (Also, one radian is a nice size for a piece of pie, which makes it very convenient.)

Comment: @EricLippert The guy who gets .2831... radian of the pie might disagree.

Comment: @Max .2831 is a little pizza-pie!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Radians provide a nice association between the area of a section of a circle and the size of the angle.  i.e. $A = \frac 12 r^2 \theta.$  They also behave nicely with arc lengths.  $C = r\theta$

And so if you have something like the rotating wheel, and you want to know the distance a belt attached to that wheel has moved, then rotation in radians avoids a conversion factor.   This makes radians handy for problems in physics and engineering.

But the bigger bonus of this association between arc length and radians comes up when $\theta$ is small.  For small $\theta, \sin\theta \approx \theta.$  And that is really important when you get to calculus.  Once you start calculus you will wonder why you ever thought degrees were easier.

We haven't really talked about polar coordinates.  And, honestly, there is no reason you cannot use degrees when you work with polar coordinates.  And plenty of "real-world" applications use degrees and polar coordinates.  Problems in navigation, for example, are almost always done in degrees, and are effectively problems in polar coordinates.

Your teachers want you to use radians to be more comfortable with them when the time comes that degrees become inefficient.

Answer (score 47):

If I were to ask you "What is a degree?", could you say anything other than "There are 360 degrees in one revolution"? And then I would ask you "Why 360? Why not 100? Why not 17? Is there anything natural about 360?"

On the other hand, radians **are** a natural measure of an angle. Given an angle, form a circle (of any radius you like) centered at the vertex of the angle. The **radian measure** of the angle is exactly the number of times the radius length fits on the arc of the angle. It's independent of whatever radius you chose.

When angles are measured in radians, you also have nice relationships between trig functions like $$(\sin \theta)' = \cos\theta$$
$$(\sin \theta)'' = -\sin \theta$$

Comment: and nice series development

Comment: As far as I know, nobody really knows why 360 degrees = 1 circle was chosen.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm 360 was chosen because it is very divisble, a 'superior highly composite number'. When you're talking about right angles you can say 90 degrees, which is a nice integer. Equilateral triangles have 60 degrees, again a nice integer. As opposed to something like "43.4 degrees" is a right angle.

Comment: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15... *and* it is exactly the same as the number of days the year! I mean, give or take a few feast days which don't really count.

Comment: The Babylonians used a base-60 counting system, so 360 is a nice round '$60' (and '6' is "round" like "2" or "5" in base 10).

Comment: @mattdm but not 16, and dividing a circle into 16 is quite common e.g. in navigation, where even 32 divisions were used. Halves, of course, aren't too bad to work with.

Comment: @MartinBonner: and since the Babylonians often didn't bother to write down the "sexagesimal point", 360 (or rather $6{;}0_{60}$) degrees in a circle actually approximated radians for them!

Comment: @mattdm : On Earth, anyway ;)

Comment: 400 has also been used.

Comment: @AlexLi -- is that a fact, or a just-so story.  360 is certainly a nice integer to use, if you are going to use an integer, but is there evidence that the decision was made intelligently, or did we just get lucky? Think of how much easier math would be if we had six or eight fingers on each hand.

Comment: @Malvolio Well, I couldn't find any hard evidence online, but many years ago, people knew enough math to understand that numbers with divisors are easier to work with than numbers without. I admit that I didn't have any real research based on what I said, but it seems very unlikely that it happened purely by luck. Google seems to agree, the general notion seems to be a combination of the divisors and there being about 360 days in a year

Answer (score 9):

The radian has a geometric meaning, it is the ratio between the arc's length and the circunference's radius.

Other measures of angle have arbitrary scales, so numerical values in degrees or gradians have no special meaning.

Maybe because of their more 'natural' definition, by using radians, we find ellegant derivatives and power series for the trigonometric functions (exponentials too, because of Euler's formula).

Answer (score 4):

1. It makes computation of circular arc lengths easier: no conversion factor like $\pi/180$ needed.
2. It makes the Taylor series for functions like $\sin$ and $\exp$ look cleaner.

But yes, it's a convention.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason is that the derivatives of sinusoidal functions only work if the angles are measured in radians.

Comment: They're certainly still differentiable, but you get an annoying constant factor.

Comment: @anomaly I didn't say they weren't differentiable. I said if you use radians, statements like (sin x)' = cos x don't hold, which is clearly true

Answer (score 2):

As many others commented, radians are the natural unit.

Degrees exist only for historical reasons and are not an extremely practical unit (not mentioning the minutes/seconds issue). One of their only assets is that $360$ is divisible by $2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10$ and others.

---

IMO, we are lacking a truly practical unit, which does not involve the constant $2\pi$: revolutions, i.e. a full turn corresponding to $1$ unit.